# Error with references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, awesomium

Currently, I'm experiencing an error while working with awesomium mono. Though the classes are clearly in the reference (`Awesomium.Mono`), Visual Studio says they can not be found and that I need to add a reference to `Awesomium.Core`. When I do this it says the references that could not be found before are now conflicting. Anyone have any ideas?

All versions are version 1.7.5.1 .

I installed awesomium by simply installing the sdk (from the website before it went down for updating). After installing the sdk I simply went into Visual Studio and added the references.

I added the references simply by right clicking references and clicking add reference. To remove it I right clicked the reference and clicked Remove.

Error Message Before Adding `Awesomium.Core`:

> The type 'WebSession' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
>       You must add a reference to assembly 'Awesomium.Core, Version=1.7.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1a0d7c8071a5214'.

Error message After adding `Awesomium.Core`:

> The type 'WebSession' exists in both 'Awesomium.Core, Version=1.7.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1a0d7c8071a5214' and 'Awesomium.Mono, Version=1.7.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=759b17c73ad53213'

Example code that will give the error at line 10:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
     // 
        // webControl1
        // 
        this.webControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.webControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.webControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1002, 502);
        this.webControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.webControl1.TargetURLChanged += new Awesomium.Core.UrlEventHandler(this.Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_TargetURLChanged);

    }
    private Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl webControl1;
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and the *exact* error message. It's very hard to help with vague statements such as "Visual Studio says they can not be found". Also please give details about which versions of the assemblies you're using, and how you've added the references. (Is this via downloaded DLLs, or nuget, or something else?)

Comment: There's the exact error message. All that chnges is adding and removing the Awesomium.Core

Comment: Thank you for the exact error message. Now please provide a [mcve] and details of how you've added the references, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the examples. It's as I said, without the Awesomium.Core some of the references from Awesomium.Mono show up with the first error message. After adding Awesomium.Core all those same references to Awesomium.Mono which have the orginal error message change to the second error message

Comment: I mean that if you could provide us a small piece of code (*just* enough to reproduce the problem) and describe how to set up the project, we could reproduce the problem. But you haven't told us where you got the assemblies from. Until we can reproduce the problem, it's going to be hard to help you. (If you could use NuGet packages instead, that would probably help, but I don't know whether there *are* suitable NuGet packages.)

Comment: Updated it again to contain the install method and the piece of code

Comment: Sorry, that's far from a [mcve]. At this stage it's probably best to wait and see if someone else will help you, rather than us just get frustrated with each other.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time.